# Where is pygame folder on mac if installed python and pygame via homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, homebrew

I used this tutorial [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Cl4Crg7FE) for pygame istallation on mac.
 The tutorial is good and I installed it all using hombrew - git, mercurial, sgl dependencies and python, pygame.

The instructions were like this.

```
brew install git
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
python3
```

At the prompt, type:

```
import pygame
```

In terminal, i do `import pygame, pygame.init()` and it works, but how do I launch it through IDE? 
**The terminal just sits there, no any other program/IDE launches after init command.**

Where did homebrew install all those folders? I can't find them in my applications, documents.

I need to know where pygame files are placed, so that I can somehow connect it to other custom IDE - PyCharm etc.

What should serve as IDE in my case? probably xCode, because the tutorial mentions it?

Answer (score 0):

After installing with homebrew, pygame seems to be connected to my other IDEs just fine. I use pycharm, and I didn't have to do anything to get pygame working with it.
However, out of my own curiosity, after much searching, I found this folder:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame

Answer (score 0):

You can run from pygame import jgsjfgjsdnfjg to find out, it will be included in the error message.